# How to use ifelse to replace the values in a column with values in another column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

For example, I merged two dataframes using full_join() in dplyr as following:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
df_2 <- data.frame(id = c(2,4,5,6,7,8), y = c('f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'))

df <- full_join(df_2, df_1, by = 'id')
```

I want to use ifelse() to do the following:

- For each row, check whether there is missing value in x column
- If yes, input "NO" into the y column
- If no, input the value of x into the y column

I tried this code:

```
df$y <- ifelse(is.null(x), "NO", x)
```

But the result was not what I wanted:

[image: This was the result]

What did I do wrong? Could you provide some suggestions on fixing the code?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you want:

```
df$y <- ifelse(is.na(df$x), "NO", df$x)
```

The problem appears to be `is.null()` where `is.na()` should be used.

Comment: Thank you! I just found out that as well :)